# My application keep crashing when I click on the convert button even though my codes have no fatal errors

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, crash, temperature

I am trying to build an application for my mini assignment, it is to create a temp converter tool. However, most of the codes out there are in java and since my assignment must be done in Kotlin. I must figure a way out myself.

This is my current code, and as you can see there are no errors, but when I click on the convert button, it will say my application crash.

**Activity.kt**

```
package edu.blabladmaoa.travelapp
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.provider.MediaStore
import android.widget.*
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import org.w3c.dom.Text


class TempConverterActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    val TAG: String = "TempConverter"

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_temp_converter)

       
        val userinput = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editTextTemp)
        val optionFah = findViewById<RadioButton>(R.id.radioButtonFah)
        val optionCel = findViewById<RadioButton>(R.id.radioButtonCel)
        val convertbutton = findViewById<Button>(R.id.convertbutton)
        val clearbutton = findViewById<Button>(R.id.clearbutton)
        val results = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tempresult)

        // now the buttons are identified, i will set the each button to have their own listener
        convertbutton.setOnClickListener{
            if (optionFah.isChecked()){
                val newinput = userinput.toString().toFloat()
                results.setText(convertCelsiusToFahrenheit(newinput).toString())
            }
            else if (optionCel.isChecked()){
                val newinput = userinput.toString().toFloat()
                convertFahrenheitToCelsius(newinput)
                results.setText(convertCelsiusToFahrenheit(newinput).toString())
            }
        }

        clearbutton.setOnClickListener{
            userinput.text.clear()
        }

    }


    
    private fun convertFahrenheitToCelsius(fahrenheit: Float): Float {
        return ((fahrenheit - 32) * 5 / 9)
    }

  
    private fun convertCelsiusToFahrenheit(celsius: Float): Float {
        return ((celsius * 9) / 5) + 32
    }

}
```

**activity.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <!--    i use "phone" to show numpad instead of normal keyboard-->

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextTemp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:hint="Enter temperature here" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButtonFah"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="to Fahrenheit" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButtonCel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="to Celcius" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/convertbutton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Convert" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/clearbutton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Clear" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tempresult"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


</LinearLayout>
```

**Android_Manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="edu.blabladmaoa.travelapp">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.TravelApp">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".TempConverterActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
 
</application>

</manifest>
```

**Expected Output**

[image: expected output of what im trying to achieve]

Comment: To clarify terms, there are no compile errors in your code, but there are runtime errors which indeed are fatal. That’s what a crash is. A compile error isn’t fatal because it prevents you from running the code in the first place. Anyway, you should check LogCat for the stack trace to see what you did wrong, and if you can’t understand it, please edit your question and include it.

Comment: I can see that your code will crash if you click the Convert button when there are not valid numbers in both EidtTexts. You should use `toFloatOrNull() ?: 0f` instead of `toFloat()` to treat invalid entries as zero. Or you might choose to show an error message instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
val newinput = userinput.toString().toFloat()
```

Here you are trying to convert an `EditText` object to a string using the `toString()` method. This will not give you the desired output.

You can access the `text` attribute of the class `EditText`. This returns the content of the EditText view as a string. Please, see below.

```
val newInput = userInput.text.toString().toFloat()
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, i already solve it. I did the same as yours, but then i use userInput.getText().toString().toFloat() rather than .text.toString().toFloat().

Btw, can i ask what is the difference between text and getText()? Or both actually works? 

@Nishant Kumar Rai

Comment: @Fumin in Kotlin, .`getText()` and `.text` are equivalent, because the private field text is accessed via its public get() method which is behind the scenes for the user of a class. For your own classes you will have to define setters and getters as in the source [link](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/properties.html#getters-and-setters)

Comment: @AndreyKachow Thank youu for more explanations :D Always love to hear diff explanations

Answer (score 0):

instead of taking the text from the input you are calling `toString()` on the `EditText` itself

you need to change

```
val newinput = userinput.toString().toFloat()
```

to

```
val newinput = userinput.text.toString().toFloat()
```

Also as mentioned by Tenfour04 in the comments it will also crash if you press convert when you leave the `EditText` empty

Comment: Thank you both Ivo Beckers and @Nishant Kumar Rai, 

I had already solved it yesterday and did a similar method. However, mine was userinput.getText().toString().toFloat() rather than userinput.text.toString().toFloat().  Can i ask what is the differnece between the two? Since it seems like both will work as well. 

I too also added an exception like, a toast to ask user to input values. So they app won't crash.

Comment: @Fumin `text` and `getText()` are the same. It's a kotlin feature called property access syntax. It basically means that any method of the form `getX()` can be called by just saying `x`.

Comment: thank you Ivo Beckers :) Now ill just use text then instead of getText(), since they are the same thing. Thank you for this explanation, helps alot in my assignment.

Answer (score 0):

You should check that your edittext isn't empty:

```
if(myEditText.getText != ""){
    //then convert
    //you should use edittext.text.tofloat
    // because the default value in edittext is String
    // and you can't convert string to float or int value 
}
```